# Why does for-for-getchar() only get 2 lines

Tags: c

The code below is the answer of minesweeper problem, m, n is length and width of game area. * represents mine, other characters represent blank, If there's mine, print '*' else print the number of mines surround. I except when I input

```
3 3
***
***
***
```

The output should be:

```
***
***
***
```

But in practice the output is:

```
2**
*6*
**2
```

And the program exit after I input the second line of ***, I have already checked it many times but can't found what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[256][256] = {0};
    int m,n,i,j;
    char c;
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);

    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            c = getchar();
            if(c=='*')
                a[i][j] = 1;
    
        }
    }
    
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            (a[i][j]==0)?printf("%d",a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j]+a[i-1][j+1]+a[i][j-1]+a[i][j+1]+a[i+1][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i+1][j+1]):printf("*");
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your data, consider your input, and by input I mean *including* any raps/taps on the enter/return key. Those don't just disappear into the ether. One was left after your two integers. Another was left after each row of chars you typed. It doesn't take but two rows to add up to three unaccounted pieces of input data.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that the newline character (`\n`) you put at the end of each line of `***` is also being registered as an input character. One possible solution is to enclose the block of `getchar()` in a [do-while](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm) loop as shown below.

```
do{
    c = getchar();
}
while(c == '\n');
```

What this check does is that it essentially ignores the newline input and goes on to the next character. It is a very hacky solution and a good start to look at the problem.

Therefore, the entire code becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[256][256] = {0};
    int m, n, i, j;
    char c;
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);

    for(i = 1; i <= m; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            do{
                c = getchar();
            }
            while(c == '\n');
            if(c == '*')
                a[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    
    for(i = 1; i <= m; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            (a[i][j] == 0) ? printf("%d", a[i-1][j-1] + a[i-1][j] + a[i-1][j+1] + a[i][j-1] + a[i][j+1] + a[i+1][j-1] + a[i+1][j] + a[i+1][j+1]) : printf("*");
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrongly thought '\n' will be cut automatically as in Python. Thank you very much.